# Process.WaitForExit() waits on command window instead of actual application

Tags: c#, .net

I want the following code to run different applications and after they have openend additional tasks.

However some applications keep an command window open whilst others do not.

e.g. outlook.exe runs just fine,

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\OUTLOOK.EXE");

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

But when running Visual Studio Code, the command window stays active in the background;

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe");

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

It seems the loaded application process is the command window and not Visual Studio Code. So the command window disappears when I remove the WaitForExit(); But then i do not know when the application has loaded.

Is there another way to know if Visual Studio Code is fully loaded?

Comment: In which OS version are you running into this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

[`Process.WaitForExit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit) waits until the process you started has actually exited (as the name suggests). If this returns while the application you started is still visible, this is because the process you started is not used. For example, an existing instance of the Outlook process that is already running might be used.

If you want to wait for the process you start to be ready to accept user input, use [`Process.WaitForInputIdle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforinputidle).

> Use WaitForInputIdle() to force the processing of your application to wait until the message loop has returned to the idle state. When a process with a user interface is executing, its message loop executes every time a Windows message is sent to the process by the operating system. The process then returns to the message loop. A process is said to be in an idle state when it is waiting for messages inside of a message loop. This state is useful, for example, when your application needs to wait for a starting process to finish creating its main window before the application communicates with that window.